# How to use google cloud printer to print text file in android

Tags: android, android-intent, printing, cloud, google-cloud-messaging

I implemented Google cloud printing in my project but when i attach text file in Google cloud then it show that 1 page to print but not show its content.

So how do I show the content of text file when file attach to google cloud and how to get existing google account from the user phone and how to make setting of google chrome to print from my code so that user easily print the doc from my app.so please provide me the code or some good tutorial to deal with google cloud in my requirement way.

```
Intent printIntent = new Intent(ExportActivity.this, PrintDialogActivity.class);
printIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/*");
printIntent.putExtra("title", "Dictionary");


public class PrintDialogActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String PRINT_DIALOG_URL = "https://www.google.com/cloudprint/dialog.html";
    private static final String JS_INTERFACE = "AndroidPrintDialog";
    private static final String CONTENT_TRANSFER_ENCODING = "base64";

    private static final String ZXING_URL = "http://zxing.appspot.com";
    private static final int ZXING_SCAN_REQUEST = 65743;

    /**
     * Post message that is sent by Print Dialog web page when the printing dialog needs to be closed.
     */
    private static final String CLOSE_POST_MESSAGE_NAME = "cp-dialog-on-close";

    /**
     * Web view element to show the printing dialog in.
     */
    private WebView dialogWebView;

    /**
     * Intent that started the action.
     */
    Intent cloudPrintIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.print_dialog);
        dialogWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        cloudPrintIntent = this.getIntent();
        WebSettings settings = dialogWebView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        dialogWebView.setWebViewClient(new PrintDialogWebClient());
        dialogWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new PrintDialogJavaScriptInterface(), JS_INTERFACE);
        dialogWebView.loadUrl(PRINT_DIALOG_URL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == ZXING_SCAN_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            dialogWebView.loadUrl(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));
        }
    }

    final class PrintDialogJavaScriptInterface {
        public String getType() {
            return cloudPrintIntent.getType();
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return cloudPrintIntent.getExtras().getString("title");
        }

        public String getContent() {
            try {
                ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
                InputStream is = contentResolver.openInputStream(cloudPrintIntent.getData());
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int n = is.read(buffer);
                while (n >= 0) {
                    baos.write(buffer, 0, n);
                    n = is.read(buffer);
                }
                is.close();
                baos.flush();

                return Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "";
        }

        public String getEncoding() {
            return CONTENT_TRANSFER_ENCODING;
        }

        public void onPostMessage(String message) {
            if (message.startsWith(CLOSE_POST_MESSAGE_NAME)) {
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private final class PrintDialogWebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith(ZXING_URL)) {
                Intent intentScan = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intentScan.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(intentScan, ZXING_SCAN_REQUEST);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException error) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                }
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (PRINT_DIALOG_URL.equals(url)) {
                // Submit print document.
                view.loadUrl("javascript:printDialog.setPrintDocument(printDialog.createPrintDocument(" + "window." + JS_INTERFACE + ".getType(),window." + JS_INTERFACE + ".getTitle()," + "window." + JS_INTERFACE + ".getContent(),window." + JS_INTERFACE + ".getEncoding()))");

                // Add post messages listener.
                view.loadUrl("javascript:window.addEventListener('message'," + "function(evt){window." + JS_INTERFACE + ".onPostMessage(evt.data)}, false)");
            }
        }
    }
}
```